# No files under package directory after adb install

Tags: android

I've installed the apk using adb install and didn't launch my app. Why it doesn't show any files under /data/data/pack_name/?

Comment: What did `adb install` output?

Comment: It gave Success result

Answer (score 0):

> didn't launch my app

`adb install` doesn't launch the app, it just installs it.

> Why it doesn't show any files under /data/data/pack_name/

It should create the directory, but it could be empty until the app creates files or folders. For Android 4.1 it always creates a `lib/` subdirectory, but it could be different for other Android versions. Also note that to list `/data/data` you need root permissions.

Comment: I understand that adb install doesn't launch app... BTW my device is rooted and lib folder is present but no other files or folders. I know these would be created if I launch app but I want to get these files without launch

Comment: The standard Android way is that your app creates them when it starts. Another solution is pushing them manually.